# В чём разница между Loader и URLLoader в ActionScript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-3, air, apache-flex

Объясните пожалуйста, в чём разница между Loader и URLLoader в ActionScript 3?
Загрузить картинку с внешнего веб-сервера можно и тем и тем классом.

Мне, новичку AS3, интересно услышать мнения профи — чем хорош тот и тот, кто ест меньше памяти, работает быстрее, и чем на практике лучше подгружать картинки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Разобрался](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=737890). «Loader — для загрузки SWF, JPG, GIF, и PNG - всего, что можно отобразить (поэтому он и определён в пэкэдже flash.display). URLLoader — для подгрузки всего остального: текста, XML и даже бинарных данных, в т.ч. и SWF или картинок, но не в случае, когда их немедленно нужно отобразить на экране.

URLLoader'ом грузят картинки в том случае, когда собираются работать с их бинарными данными в ByteArray.»

Answer (score 0):

`URLLoader`, скажем так, загрузчик более низкого уровня, он не создаёт контейнера для загруженных данных, позволяет контролировать процесс загрузки. `Loader` является контейнером для загружаемых данных, т.е. после загрузки они появятся в `Loader` в качестве потомка. Помимо этого, `Loader` позволяет преобразовывать `byteArray` в изображение например, если этот `byteArray` отдан нам со стороны, например, через `JS`.